# Delphi: "IndexOF" an Object in an Array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I got an Array of TPoint. Now I was wondering if there is something out there like:

```
apts: TArray<TPoint>;
//
if (apts.indexOF(p1) < 0) do smth
```

so is there some procedure that actually searches an array for something ( in this case point (p1) )
and returns me the Index of it?

Comment: If you use `TList<TPoint>` instead, there is [IndexOf()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.IndexOf).

Comment: Are you looking for your TPoint object or the first TPoint object that contains the same coordinates?

Comment: Hmm, [System.Types.TPoint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Types.TPoint) is a record not an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `TArray` static class in `Generics.Collections` has a binary search, but no linear search. I fill that particular gap like this:

```
type
  TArray = class(Generics.Collections.TArray)
  public
    class function Contains<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T;
      const Comparer: IEqualityComparer<T>; out ItemIndex: Integer): Boolean;
      overload; static;
    class function Contains<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T;
      out ItemIndex: Integer): Boolean; overload; static;
    class function Contains<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T): Boolean;
      overload; static;
    class function IndexOf<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T;
      const Comparer: IEqualityComparer<T>): Integer; overload; static;
    class function IndexOf<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T): Integer;
      overload; static;
  end;

class function TArray.Contains<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T;
  const Comparer: IEqualityComparer<T>; out ItemIndex: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  for Index := 0 to high(Values) do begin
    if Comparer.Equals(Values[Index], Item) then begin
      ItemIndex := Index;
      Result := True;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  ItemIndex := -1;
  Result := False;
end;

class function TArray.Contains<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T;
  out ItemIndex: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Contains<T>(Values, Item, TEqualityComparer<T>.Default, ItemIndex);
end;

class function TArray.Contains<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T): Boolean;
var
  ItemIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result := Contains<T>(Values, Item, ItemIndex);
end;

class function TArray.IndexOf<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T;
  const Comparer: IEqualityComparer<T>): Integer;
begin
  Contains<T>(Values, Item, Comparer, Result);
end;

class function TArray.IndexOf<T>(const Values: array of T; const Item: T): Integer;
begin
  Contains<T>(Values, Item, Result);
end;
```

My static class has a whole load more functions, but these are the ones you need for this purpose.

This code relies on the default equality comparer for your type being fit for purpose. That is the case for a simple type like `TPoint`, but be prepared for surprises if you use more complex types for which the default comparers are insufficient.

Comment: that totally solved my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: A second routine `IndexOf()` accepting an additional `IEqualityComparer<T>` might be useful, so the user can generate a comparer using `TEqualityComparer<T>.Construct()`.

Comment: And I would probably have a `Contains<T>` without `ItemIndex`, and base it on `IndexOf`. But that is personal preference. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's arbitrary which way round you do it. Do it your way if you prefer.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I added overloads that accept a comparer