# Is there a way to find the index of an item of an array of pointers?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-2009

Is there a way to find the index of an item of an array of pointers ?

The code is like this:

```
type

  TArrayItem = record
   Field1: string;
   Field2: integer;
   Field3: boolean;
  end;

var 
  MyItem: TArrayItem; 
  MyArray: array[1..100] of TArrayItem;
```

Let's say I take an item from the array (`MyItem:=MyArray[20];`). After this I sort the array and the item locations are changed; Now, how can I find the new index of `MyItem` ?

Comment: You haven't got an array of pointers. What if there are multiple identical items? Why are you using constant sized arrays? Why are you using 1 based arrays?

Comment: Iterate through the array looking for MyArray[Index] = MyItem.

Comment: See [Delphi: “IndexOF” an Object in an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26359995/576719).

Comment: @Ken you cannot use `=` on records

Comment: You may want to expose the real problem you are trying to solve, because sorting array completely replaces ordering of elements. Mapping to previous ordering after sorting is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @David: Sure you can, if you overload the equality operator. But you're correct - I read "pointers" and didn't notice "record" in the type declaration. Glad I posted a comment and not an answer. :-)

Comment: @Ken Yes. But that's not the case here. Ok, comments crossed.

Comment: @David: You replied before I got my comment edit in. Sorry.

Comment: Do you want to know what is an index of former Nth element in new array? I.e. to find index mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an array of pointers.  Unlike a `class`, which is a reference type, a `record` is a value type. The way you have declared the array, the item data is copied whenever you do an assignment.  So hen you assign an array item to `MyItem`, you are making a *copy* of that item's data, you are not obtaining a pointer to the original item.

In any case, whether you have an array of items or an array of pointers to items, the answer is the same: the only way to find an item in an array is to loop through the array manually, eg:

```
var 
  MyItem: TArrayItem; 
  MyArray: array[1..100] of TArrayItem;
  I: Integer;

MyItem := MyArray[20];

// sort the array...

for I := Low(MyArray) to High(MyArray) do
begin
  if (MyArray[I].Field1 = MyItem.Field1) and
     (MyArray[I].Field2 = MyItem.Field2) and
     (MyArray[I].Field3 = MyItem.Field3) then
  begin
    // item was found at index I...
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, dynamically allocate your items on the heap and store their pointers in a `TList` or `TList<T>`, as they expose `IndexOf()` methods.  And sorting would be faster since you are only moving pointers around, not complete copies of data.

Comment: The distinction between heap and stack isn't the key here. What is key is that records are values rather than references. Suppose the array was declared as a member of a class. Then it would be allocated on the heap, but that would not change any of the issues discussed.

Comment: I think I've made an mistake. In the code posted in the question I declared the array as a static array, for simplicity, but in my real code I have an dinamic array that can grow verry large. Does that make any difference ?

Comment: No. Your array elements are still value types, not reference types, so when you move them around, you are moving around full copies of the data, not pointers.

Comment: @MarusNebunu, it makes a difference in that the question then is identical to [Delphi: “IndexOF” an Object in an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26359995/576719).

Answer (score 4):

There is no intrinsic mechanic for doing what you ask.  You will have to iterate over the array and identify the matching item in order to identify it's position in that array.

In this case you should also note that although your question states that you have an "array of pointers", the code you have posted is **not** an array of pointers but an array of *records*, which are value types not references, so this code:

```
MyItem := MyArray[20];
```

Does not obtain a reference to the 20th item in **MyArray**, but rather it creates a copy of it.  The code for identifying an item in an array varies quite markedly when you are locating a copy of an item versus a reference to an item.

To find an item in an array of pointers:

```
var
   i, indexOfItem: Integer;
   item: ^TArrayItem;
   theArray: array[1..100] of ^TArrayItem;


item := theArray[20];

indexOfItem := -1;
for i := Low(theArray) to High(theArray) do
  if (theArray[i] = item) then
  begin
    indexOfItem := i;
    BREAK;
  end;
```

To find an item in an array of records you have to test equality of the record fields separately since you cannot compare two records as a whole:

```
var
   i, indexOfItem: Integer;
   item: TArrayItem;
   theArray: array[1..100] of TArrayItem;


item := theArray[20];

indexOfItem := -1;
for i := Low(theArray) to High(theArray) do
  if   (theArray[i].Field1 = item.Field1) 
   and (theArray[i].Field2 = item.Field2) 
   and (theArray[i].Field3 = item.Field3) then
  begin
    indexOfItem := i;
    BREAK;
  end;
```

You should also be aware that in this latter case there is a built in assumption that no two items will have the same values for the record fields, since only the first matching item will be identified.

**NB.** *The code above is not intended to be robust solutions, only to demonstrate the principles involved*.

One last thing to be aware of is the possibility that you have an array of records but have obtained a **pointer** to some item in that array prior to sorting the array:

```
var
   item: ^TArrayItem;
   theArray: array[1..100] of TArrayItem;


item := @theArray[20];
SortTheArray(theArray);
```

If this is the case then after sorting the array (or any form of manipulation of that array) the value of the **item** pointer may *no longer be reliable at all* for a dynamic array, since the array may have moved in memory as a result of the operations performed on it!

Even if the array has not moved, as is currently the case with a static array, the item pointer will point to whichever item is *now* at the 20th position in that array, not the item that *was* in that position prior to the sort.

Comment: In the final example, `theArray` is going nowhere. It's a value. It cannot be moved. You can take its address as many times as you like and the value is always the same

Comment: For a static array that is true (today, though I'm not sure it's guaranteed to remain true in any/all future versions of the compiler).  For a dynamic array it absolutely is not so certain.  Either way, as I point out, even if the array doesn't move, your pointer to an item in that array is useless for "tracking" that items position in the array.  Have added clarification on this point to the answer.

Comment: LOL - interesting to note that it has now emerged that the OP's actual case is actually a dynamic array which they "simplified" to a static array for the purposes of posting the code in the question.  ;)

Comment: Arrays aren't meant to be sorted, use a TList instead.

Comment: @Pieter Not so. Arrays are absolutely meant to be sorted.